# How do I pause or delay blinking text animation, so my text displays for a short period of time?

Tags: css, css-animations

I have a button with some text that blinks, however I want to delay it for a short time when the text is visible, giving the user enough time to read the text before it fades to transparent.

```
.btn-blink{
 border: 2px solid #4aa570;
 margin-bottom:20px;
 color:#fff;background:#4aa570;
 animation:blinkingText 3.2s infinite;
}

@keyframes blinkingText{
    0%{ color: #fff;    }
    25%{color: transparent; }
    50%{color: #fff;    }
    75%{color: transparent;}
    100%{color: #fff;   }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Disperse the transitions in your @keyframes by percentage to make it irregular.

```
@keyframes blinkingText {
    0% {color: #fff;}
    50% {color: #fff;}
    75% {color: transparent;}
    100% {color: #fff;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope below code will be helpful.Below is HTML code.

```
//HTML CODE
<button>
  <span class="blinking">HELLO THERE</span>
</button>
```

Write CSS code as below using keyframes:

```
//CSS 
.blinking{
   animation:blinkingText 0.8s infinite;
}

@keyframes blinkingText{
 0%{ color: #000;}
 49%{ color: transparent; }
 50%{ color: transparent; }
 99%{ color:transparent; }
 100%{ color: #000; }
}
```

I hope you will find your answer.